# Adding new nodes into the DOM and checking if they are present

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a function that adds new `<li>` elements into the DOM on the fly. After it is done the DOM looks similar to this but with more `<li>` tags:

```
<ul class='map-listings'>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

I have a button `<button onclick="filtersLogic(evt, 'dWeb')">` and a function that looks like this:

```
function filtersLogic(evt, tabName){
    var i;
    var mapListings = $('.map-listings').childNodes;
    alert('clicked')
    if (tabName == 'dWeb'){
        alert('fired')
        if (mapListings.length != 0){
            alert(mapListings.length) 
        }
    }
}
```

So far I can get all the way to the point where my function alerts `'fired'` but nothing appears for `mapListings.length`.

Comment: you may be interested in **$('.map-listings li')** instead of **$('.map-listings').childNodes** .  childNodes is not a jQuery prop

Comment: Not related, but you need `event` in an inline handler to get the event object. `<button onclick="filtersLogic(event, 'dWeb')">`

Comment: ...actually, it is related, since `evt` should be giving you a *ReferenceError* when invoked, unless it's defined elsewhere, which doesn't seem likely.

Comment: @SkinnyPete Could you explain what that means further?

Comment: Yes, the parameter name `evt` should be spelled out as `event` because  the *string* you provided to the `onclick` attribute becomes the *body* of a function assigned to that element. The event object is passed to that function as the first function parameter, which has the full name `event`. So in order to use it, you need to give the correct parameter name. It's basically the same as this. `myElement.onclick = function(event) { filtersLogic(event, 'dWeb'); }`. So you can see that your string is now the actual function body, and if you had `evt` instead of `event`, it would fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will get the list of `<li>` elements inside the `<ul class="map-listings">` element.

Then it changes the background and foreground colors of each of them.

```js
function filtersLogic(event, tabName){
  if (tabName == 'dWeb'){
    var els = document.querySelectorAll('.map-listings > li');
    console.log('Elements found:', els.length) 
    els.forEach(
      function(el) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        el.style.color = "white";
      }
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="filtersLogic(event, 'dWeb')">click me</button>
<ul class='map-listings'>
 <li>jdfkajdl</li>
 <li>fdsafsadf</li>
 <li>gfdsgdfsg</li>
 <li>trewrew</li>
 <li>ghfddfg</li>
</ul>
```

If you want to keep it as jQuery then use this:

```js
function filtersLogic(event, tabName){
  if (tabName == 'dWeb'){
    var els = $('.map-listings > li');
    console.log('Elements found:', els.length) 
    els.css('backgroundColor', 'black');
    els.css('color', 'white');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="filtersLogic(event, 'dWeb')">click me</button>
<ul class='map-listings'>
 <li>jdfkajdl</li>
 <li>fdsafsadf</li>
 <li>gfdsgdfsg</li>
 <li>trewrew</li>
 <li>ghfddfg</li>
</ul>
```

I just like getting away from jQuery where possible.

Comment: repeating ens.css twice. Why? Also, use ***Strict equality*** `===` instead of `==`

Comment: No need for strict equality when I know both sides are strings. And I haven't written live JQuery in years so the two `els.css` are because I forgot you could combine them. But again, I avoid jQuery now every chance I get. Vanilla JS is faster.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use inline JS - it's hard to maintain
- use jQuery's `.find()` to sarch for child nodes
- Say hi to `data-*` attributes and jQuery's `.data()` method

```js
function filtersLogic(evt){

    var mapListings = $('.map-listings').find("li"); // Use jQuery's .find()

    if ($(this).data("tabname") === "dWeb"){
        alert('fired')
        if (mapListings.length){
            alert(mapListings.length) 
        }
    }
}


$("#filtersLogic").on("click", filtersLogic);
```

```html
<ul class='map-listings'>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>
<button id="filtersLogic" data-tabname="dWeb"> CLICK </button>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Inline JS, when just a function call, is no harder to maintain than adding a class to hook up a handler and a data attribute to store some data. jQuery's `.data()` should be avoided unless you actually *want* a duplicate reference to the data. This is usually only the case if you need to mutate the data and track it throughout the program.

Comment: `var mapListings = $('.map-listings li')` is faster then `var mapListings = $('.map-listings').find("li");` since it only calls `querySelectorAll` one time.